# shell alias has cache? Why?

Tags: android, bash, shell, alias

I write a alias command for get version of android in PC using adb shell, like this:

```
alias av="echo v:`adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release`;
          echo sdk:`adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk`;
          echo model:`adb shell getprop  ro.product.model`;
          echo  display:`adb shell getprop ro.build.display.id`;"
```

I connect one device, it right outputs :

```
v:4.0.4
sdk:15
model:ZTE N983
display:N983V1.0.0B06
```

But when I change another device. It also output last text. When i open new shell, it output rights again. Why?

Alias has a cache? How to solve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backticks are evaluated immediately.

Use something like

```
alias av="echo -n v; adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release; ..."
```

to make the adb commands be executed at the time of alias execution.

Comment: Or use single quotes.

Comment: Or don't use an alias but use a function.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use shell file or function. I want to find a more portable or clean way like in home shell

Answer (score 0):

The final result

1 alias av="echo -n v:; adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release; echo -n sdk:;adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk; \
        echo -n model:;adb shell getprop  ro.product.model; echo -n display:;adb shell getprop ro.build.display.id";

2 alias av='echo v: `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release`; echo sdk: `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk`; echo model: `adb shell getprop  ro.product.model`; echo display: `adb shell getprop ro.build.display.id`'

But The second way cannot begin a new line using \